# Best style for deleting all constructors (or other function)?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, delete-operator

Let's say I want to make a type that cannot be constructed (don't ask why).

```
struct Impossible
{
```

I could do it like this:

```
    Impossible() = delete;
    // disable automatically generated constructors, don't declare any others
    Impossible(const Impossible&) = delete;
    // I suppose this is redundant with nothing to copy
```

or like this:

```
    Impossible(...) = delete;
    // explicitly disable all constructors
```

or like this:

```
    template<typename... Ts>
    Impossible(Ts...) = delete;
    // explicitly disable all constructors, template version
};
```

I guess I could ask the same thing about any function, not just constructors.

Does it make any difference which one I choose? In terms of syntax I think I like the second option. But is there any situation, whatsoever, where it's possible to detect a difference (other than in the text of an error message)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference, for example:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Unconstructible
{
    Unconstructible() = delete;
};

static_assert( !std::is_default_constructible<Unconstructible>::value, "not default constructible" );
static_assert( std::is_copy_constructible<Unconstructible>::value, "copyable" );
```

Although you can never construct this object, so in practice you can never create a copy of one either, according the language and the type traits in the library, it is technically CopyConstructible, because there's an implicitly-declared copy constructor.

Similarly, with the `Impossible(...)` or `Impossible(Ts&&...)` forms there is still an implicitly-declared copy constructor.

On the other hand, if you do it this way:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Unconstructible
{
    Unconstructible(const Unconstructible&) = delete;
};

static_assert( !std::is_default_constructible<Unconstructible>::value, "not default constructible" );
static_assert( !std::is_copy_constructible<Unconstructible>::value, "not copyable" );
```

The existence of a user-declared constructor suppresses the implicit declaration of the default constructor, so the class is neither DefaultConstructible nor CopyConstructible.

---

N.B. your last example should probably be `Impossible(Ts&&...)` to match *any* types, including non-copyable and non-movable ones.

Comment: Wait. Even if I explicitly declare a more-general constructor that meets the requirements for being a copy constructor (it accepts an argument of the self-type), and delete it, the compiler will still generate /another/ copy constructor, which is a better match after considering overloading? Is that definitely right?

Comment: Yes. [class.copy]/2 _A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`,
`volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments._ [class.copy]/7 _If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly._ So the more-general constructor is not technically a "copy constructor" even though it can be used to copy the type.

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks! (And mea culpa regarding `Ts...`. For some reason I was thinking that the types would be deduced to be *anything* (reference, rvalue reference, whatever) as necessary depending on what was passed, but upon reflection that's obviously dumb. Just because it's a parameter *pack* won't make it magically behave differently from single parameters. (As opposed to rvalue references to template parameters which *do* behave magically in a similar sort of way to enable perfect forwarding, as you said.))

Answer (score 8):

The first one is more than enough - no constructors will be generated by the compiler and, **most imporatantly, it's idiomatic**.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create instance of this class:

```
struct Impossible
{
    Impossible() = delete;
};
```

Note the question of copy-constructor (or move-constructor) doesn't even arise, so deleting them is unnecessary. An object cannot exist because it cannot be *constructed*, so the copying or moving is out of question.

Comment: Yep, as I mentioned. But I'm curious about the "any possible way to detect" part of it. Is there _any_ code you can write that will behave differently depending on which style I chose? Say, using SFINAE?